# SharedPreferences saves state between android activities but not upon restarting the app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm running to a really weird behavior with SharedPreferences. I'm wondering if I'm running into a synchronization issue.

It seems like the app can remember the preference changes in between activities but not when I restart the app. The state always returns back to the very first instance I created a preference. I've followed several examples, tutorials, and android documentation that all suggest similar code layout. I also watched how the preference.xml file changed while interacting with my code using the debugger and I confirmed it looked like the key value pair updated.

Could I be experiencing a synchronization issue with my emulator? I tried using both the editor.apply() method and editor.commit() method with the same results.
The only thing I've found that fixes my problem is using the editor.clear() method, but this feels a bit hacky...

note: please forgive the variable names, I'm making a pokedex...

```java
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean caught;
    private Set<String> pokemonCaught;
    private String pokemonName;

    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES = "shared_preferences";
    public static final String PREF_KEY = "inCaughtState";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        /*SKIPPING THE VIEW SETUP*/
        /*SKIPPING BUTTON VIEW ATTRIBUTES*/

        //variables required for changing button state
        pokemonName = (String) nameTextView.getText();
        caught = false;

        //Loading in sharedPreferences

        sharedPreferences =
                getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        pokemonCaught = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(PREF_KEY, new HashSet<String>());
        if (pokemonCaught.contains(pokemonName)) {
            toggleCatch(catchButton);
        }
    }

    public void toggleCatch (View view) {

        //Editing and updating preferences
        sharedPreferences =
                getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        if (caught == true) {
            /*SKIPPING BUTTON ATTRIBUTES*/
            caught = false;
            pokemonCaught.remove(pokemonName);
        }
        else {
            /*SKIPPING BUTTON ATTRIBUTES*/
            caught = true;
            pokemonCaught.add(pokemonName);
        }

        editor.clear(); //This is my hacky solution...
        editor.putStringSet(PREF_KEY, pokemonCaught);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: you show us who do you get sharedPreference, but didn't show us how do you add stuff into sharedPreference as you only add them under a condition that won't met until you first add something to the sharedPreference

Comment: ah, I realize now that this is unclear: toggleCatch is initiated when a button is pressed. And in the onCreate function,getStringSet will return a new HashSet for the pokemonCaught set, so that the editor in the toggleCatch function has a Set to save. I'll add this to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SharedPreferences this way:

To save data

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("stringName", "stringValue");
            editor.apply();
```

To retrieve data

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = preferences.getString("stringName", "none"));
```

Note that this "none" is in case to string "stringName" be null.